# .htaccess RewriteRule regex match specific words

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need an advice from someone which is a better expert in rewrite rules and regex expressions than me.

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /product.php?prod=$1 [L]
```

It basically rewrites any page between the slashes to product.php

```
www.website.com/prod1/
www.website.com/prod2/
www.website.com/apple/
www.website.com/orange/
```

However, I would like to only rewrite specific pages like:

```
www.website.com/apple/
www.website.com/orange/
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `^(apple|orange)/$ /product.php?prod=$1 [L]`

Comment: @MarkShevchenko I was just writing exaclty that as the answer. If you write it as an answer I'll upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help:

RewriteRule ^(apple|orange)/$ /product.php?prod=$1 [L]

Comment: Definitely helps. Thank you, Mark!